# How does a service choose which pod to send request to?

Tags: kubernetes

I understand what a Cluster IP service is and everything, I just don't understand the 'behind the scenes' and routing. Can someone PLEASE explain it to me!

1. A request is made to the Cluster IP service. If this service is serving multiple pods, how does the service choose which pod to send the request to, what is controlling and deciding that?
2. Once a pod is chosen and the request is sent to it are there iptables (added by kube-proxy) within that pod mapping the service to its corresponding pods and the pod then forwards/load-balances that request off again? unless it's that pods turn to process the request?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Let me try my best to help you out. Cluster IP is not exposed to the outer network it is automated and K8s manage its traffic in the round-robin scheme. It also depends upon resources. Let's suppose you have one Frontend app and it has 4 pods with cluster-IP service running on 4 working nodes of k8s. These CLuster IPs talking to a backend app. Now k8s will auto-scal the load accordingly. It all depends on what policies you have set for resources ( Like how much CPU RAM or storage each pod can use). If you don't set any policies the resources can be auto-scale. It also depends on which pod is running on which node and what the spec of each node has(maybe one node is more powerful than the other). Let's say one pod is running on node-x which is the most powerful node and you don't have any resource policies on the pod level then most of the traffic will go to that pod which is running on the powerful node. If you have all the nodes with equal specs and no pod-level policies then K8s will distribute the traffic equally on each pod. K8s decide with leftover resources on the node level to distribute the traffic and it's done by Scheduler API. I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you PLEASE elaborate my two questions and answer those specifically?

Comment: When we assign a service to any deployment or RS then service group all the pods and provide a single point of access.  In your example, all the pods have one single point of access which is your ClusterIP service. Now, when any connection request comes ClusterIp diverts this request to any pod randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Please find your answers below.

1. By default kubernetes algorithm decide based on round robin routing, but if you want you can use specific algorithm to route the traffic but that is only possible if proxy is running in IPVS mode or you can use session affinity, if you want to transfer the traffic to specific pod based on user cookie or something else.
2. Partially yes, usually kubernetes follow labeling concept for determining the pod and then based on that it will route the request, so it will mainly work based on dns based pod ip resolution mechanism. But if it is egress traffic then kubernetes usage iptables to handle the same.

For more details read these two blogs.

- https://dustinspecker.com/posts/iptables-how-kubernetes-services-direct-traffic-to-pods/#add-a-virtual-ip-in-iptables
- https://technekey.com/changing-the-traffic-distribution-of-a-kubernetes-service/

Hope this give you more detailed idea. Thanks!!

Comment: Can you please elaborate and answer the following questions though? thank you

1. A request is made to the Cluster IP service. If this service is serving multiple pods, how does the service choose which pod to send the request to, what is controlling and deciding that?

2. Once a pod is chosen and the request is sent to it are there iptables (added by kube-proxy) within that pod mapping the service to its corresponding pods and the pod then forwards/load-balances that request off again? unless it's that pods turn to process the request?

Comment: 1. For pod traffic kubernetes usage a round robin mechanism by default, that means it will send the request one by one to each pod and follow the same.  2. For each Service, it installs iptables rules, which capture traffic to the Service's clusterIP and port , and redirect that traffic to one of the Service's backend sets. For each endpoint, it installs iptables rules which select a backend Pod. By default, kube-proxy in iptables mode chooses a backend at random.